# WYSIWYG JavaFX for Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, xcode, javafx

Is there any option to use Scene Builder to create ui for Android application like in Xcode?
I'm familiar with xcode and Obj-C for IOS development and Netbeans + sceneBuilder (JAVA) for cross platform development and I'm looking for a easy and reliable way to develop for Android platform using JavaFX.

I know about Android studio but I'm looking for something more WYSIWYG approach.

Comment: I don't get the question... Are you looking for an IDE with Scene Builder integration?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way or a tool to develop using WYSIWYG approach (similar to XCODE and IOS), to develop for android platform

Comment: If your look for a WYSIWYG approach, then please edit your post to more clearly convey what you're looking for.

Comment: So why can't you use Scene Builder to build your ui? Last time I checked Scene Builder was WYSIWYG.

Comment: I need to build my app for android and I have clarified my question

Answer (score 3):

As @mipa points out, if you want to use JavaFX for developing for Android, [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com) provides:

- [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/), an open source project to port JavaFX to iOS and Android.
- [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) binaries from the OpenJFX repository, and new updates.

Since you are able to use JavaFX, you can use Scene Builder to generate fxml files as resources for your project. Those can be loaded as in any regular JavaFX project, and then deployed on any platform.

Have a look at the HelloWorldFXML sample at the JavaFXPorts [repository](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples) to get you started.

As well, you will find:

- [Gluon Plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/) for NetBeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse, a free gradle plugin, so you can create a JavaFX project on any of these, and deploy it on Desktop, iOS and Android.
- [Gluon Charm](http://gluonhq.com/products/charm/), a commercial library to enhance your JavaFX project (native UI, access to cloud, access to native services on your device).

The sample [Notes](http://gluonhq.com/learn-to-build-gluon-charm-apps-with-three-new-charm-samples/) at Gluon's [repository](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples) uses fxml files for defining different Views, while Charm takes care of switching between them.

Comment: This is great answer, do you know if it will harm the app performance dramatically compared to native app?

Comment: The best way for you to see about performance is test it. There are already some apps on Google Play created with JavaFXPorts: [JavaOne app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gluonhq.applications.javaone), [Ensemble](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.javafxports.ensemble8), [2048FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jpereda.game2048).